# Not able to include Date.php when the cron function runs

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

If i run my code on local server it is working fine , but its not running when i integrate online ,it is not able to include Date.php

```
    include_once('database.php');
echo "database";
    include ("Date.php");// 
echo "date";
```

but both php files are in the same folder

Comment: Does your data file have a capital letter?

Comment: Where is this `Date.php` located? same as `database.php`?

Comment: check the path is correct by using if file_exists('database.php')

Comment: Let me ask what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Mithun will do it sure!!! and both the files are in the same application folder...only database.php is included...No error message... its pure php.... so if i echo a date ..it should show it... but now its not able to...

Comment: @Jleagle have checked it.. its the same

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
  include_once('database.php');
echo "database";
    include_once('Date.php');// 
echo "date";
```

Note that you have a space after the include function.
Also check if the capital letter is correct for Date.php filename.

Eric

Comment: What in that space after the include function? And do you think any magic will happen on changing the double quotes to single quotes in this `include_once` statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
include ("XXXXXX.com/CronFunWorks/Date.php");
```

just included the path